Use single Jenkins pipeline for all the repositories in a GitHub Organisation
I have seen a few answers in Stack overflow for this but those are quite generic. I'm a beginner and have no idea about it.
My team wants to implement a single Jenkins pipeline for all the repositories in a GitHub organisation. This is because we keep seeing a new repository being added frequently. All the repositories use develop branch for build as a standard. These are mule applications and use maven for build, individual repo build requirements may vary but we would still use one pipeline for all repos.
I can't see GitHub organisation option while creating Jenkins job as well.

When you are talking about "GitHub organisation option" you have the classic setup in mind: workflow-multibranch, github-branch-source, and following this doc. It's the recommended way of doing things in Jenkins, but keep in mind that you still need one Jenkinsfile per repo.
If you really don't want to have a Jenkinsfile in every repo you would have to improvise. And before you head down that road you can read this doc to understand what have been tried and how we ended up with the setup above.
